# Send message when bot joins server [Discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm currently making a discord bot and would like to send a message in the `#general` channel of a server when it joins, this is the code that I have so far.

```
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    general = find(lambda x: x.name == 'general',  guild.text_channels)
    if general and general.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="**======== *Thanks For Adding Me!* ========**", description=f"""
        Thanks for adding me to {guild.name}!
        You can use the `--help` command to get started!
        """, color=0xd89522)
        await general.send(embed=embed)
```

When i run this code noting happens. I dont get any erorrs or output.

If anyone could help, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a message when the bot joins a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834656/send-a-message-when-the-bot-joins-a-server)

Answer (score 1):

Does your `on_guild_join` have the [event decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=event#discord.Client.event) (`@client.event`)?  When I test your code with this decorator it works fine.

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    general = find(lambda x: x.name == 'general',  guild.text_channels)
    if general and general.permissions_for(guild.me).send_messages:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="**======== *Thanks For Adding Me!* ========**", description=f"""
        Thanks for adding me to {guild.name}!
        You can use the `--help` command to get started!
        """, color=0xd89522)
        await general.send(embed=embed)
```

In addition, you may want to have a fallback in case the guild your bot joins does not have a channel named "general".  It may be more reliable to send a message in `guild.text_channels[0]`, which will send the message in the first channel, or `guild.system_channel` to send a message in the system channel.

Answer (score -1):

```
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="**======== *Thanks For Adding Me!* ========**", description=f"Thanks for adding me to {guild.name}"!You can use the `--help` commandto get started!"", color=0xd89522)
    await guild.text_channels[0].send(embed=embed)
```